# Making apache 2.2.11 parse .wml files as PHP?

Tags: php, apache, parsing, wap, wml

I've tried a variety of combinations, the following being my last attempt:

```
Addtype text/vnd.wap.wml wml
Addtype image/vnd.wap.wbmp wbmp
AddType text/vnd.wap.wmlscript wmls
AddType application/vnd.wap.wmlc wmlc
AddType application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc wmlsc

AddType application/x-httpd-php .wml
```

How can I get Apache 2.2.11 to parse .wml files as PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .wml
```

Should work. I may be possible (in case of SuPHP or custom mime-type settings) that the x-httpd-php part is not correct. Please check your configuration what mimetype is actually used for PHP.

Comment: Ok. It works. I dont know why, or how it's different from what I did just now... but it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .wml
```

Explicitly specifying PHP5 is sometimes required.

Answer (score 1):

AddType doesn't work .. AddHandler should be used . try adding the following to apache conf :

> AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .wml

it should work.